# IdentityServer 4 navigating to Login Screen when switching between applications even Access Token/Id Token is valid. Any insights?

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

We are facing issue as Identity Server 4 is throwing us frequently (2-3 times a day) to Login screen when switching between apps (Implicit Flow - Angular). There is no issues/events raised in IDSrv logging.

Example:

Login to Application 1 with Client Name say 'First_Client',

Another Application 2 uses the same client 'First_Client'.

Application 2 should automatically Login and does not require credentials to re-enter but 3 out of 10 times, it failed and silently navigates to Login screen without raising any Log Events

*Earlier we were facing it very less but now its too frequent. Quick help would be appreciated*

**Is there any issue with IDsrv configuration set up? I mean Cookies set up, Authentication set up etc.**

**Note: In my case, Identity Server is deployed on two servers for load balancing.**

Below is the configuration:

Startup.cs => ConfigureServices()
[image]

Startup.cs => Configure()

[image]

Comment: Your authentication cookie lifetime is pretty short (1 hour) and it's pot luck if sliding expiration kicks in (it'd require a request to come after half the interval had elapsed) so are you sure it's not just because of that?

Comment: @mackie Thanks for quick reply. Let me test by increasing the cookie expiry time. What your insights about Load Balancer plays any role in the issue?

Comment: Ah sorry I missed the point about a load balancer on first skim. That could well be significant if you're not employing shared storage for both token signing keys and the data protection keys used by ASP.Net itself to secure the auth cookie. There's a checklist of things to consider here: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/deployment.html

Comment: Do you have any running example for that. I mean any codebase where I can see the implementation to get some insights

Comment: Not to hand but the linked documentation contains links to the relevant docs for each aspect that needs shared storage. What you choose will depend on your specific deployment.

Comment: Thanks @mackie. Will check

Comment: As @mackie is saying one hour for a session cookie is short. It depends on your use case of course. Its short for a shop, but it might not be for a bank. Anyway, if you're load balacing the session is only alive in one server, so you'll need to activate session affinity. Session affinity consists on setting a cookie on the client the first time it contacts us. This cookie identifies one of the service instances, so every time the clients speask with our server, they do talk to the same server. Also if you're using opaque tokens and instrospection, you need both svc share the operational store.

Comment: @mackie: Increasing Cookie lifetime didn't worked. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know

Comment: @GhanshyamShukla load balancing and your application not sharing data protection keys between nodes (these keys are used to encrypt and sign the cookie payload amongst other things) is likely the culprit then. Check out the link in my Oct 27 comment above, it'll tell you what you need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple copies of the same service, you need to make sure the cookie is acceptable by all of them. By default, a cookie from one service is not valid in a different service.

The session cookie by default contains your access tokens.

You need to configure the Data Protection API to use a shared private key across the services that should accept the same cookie.

See this link for details:

- [Data Protection configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Before adding Data Protection, I guess I should try code like below:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.SetIdentityServerOrigin("https://myidentitserver.com");
     await next();
});
The issuer uri is "https://myidentitserver.com/identity". 
Any comments/advise?

Comment: Getting the origin/identity/proxy to work with one instance I think is the first step, then fix data protection, it is relevant for both single and multiple instance setups. For your question I don't have any experience with setting up load balanced IS-setups